# OpenAPI java generated client Class not found error

Tags: node.js, spring-boot, maven, gson, openapi-generator

I have an issue with OpenAPI generator for Java client. 
I am using nodeJs openApi generator to generate a Java api client with :

```
npx openapi-generator generate -i .\swagger.yaml -g java -o ./output -c config.yaml
```

then use mvn package to package the output and integrate it to my spring-boot application. 
My problem appears everytime I try to create an instance of my api. I get this error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/gsonfire/GsonFireBuilder
```

I checked to generated pom and I can see that the dependencies are there:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>${gson-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.gsonfire</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson-fire</artifactId>
            <version>${gson-fire-version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Thanks

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you want to generate a java client from swagger, why don't you use swagger tools, simply copy your yaml into editor.swagger.io and generate java client.

Comment: I would suggest you to use maven openapi-generator-maven-plugin to do that, since you are using maven and are in the Java world